# How to get entire html after dynamic content is loaded in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2022-23

I am able to do it partially. There is a show more button when clicked will load more matches. After clicking when I try to return html, only page which was loaded before clicking show more is returned.

After searching a bit found an example like this to solve the issue.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".class1.class2")))
```

But I dont think there are any new elements that are created after show more.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
from seleniumwire import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()        
url = "https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/2022-23"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="widgetLite-9"]/button')
link.click()

source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")    
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
div_tags = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'fixres__body'})
soup = div_tags[0]

matches = []
date_tags = soup.find_all('h4', class_='fixres__header2')
for tag in tags:
    if tag.name == 'h4':
        date = tag.text.strip()
    elif tag.name == 'div' and tag['class'] == ['fixres__item']:
        team1 = tag.find('span', class_='matches__participant--side1').text.strip()
        team2 = tag.find('span', class_='matches__participant--side2').text.strip()
        match_time = tag.find('span', class_='matches__date').text.strip()      
        matches.append([date, match_time, team1, team2])
        
with open('matches.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Time', 'Team 1', 'Team 2'])  # Write the header row
    writer.writerows(matches)

print(len(matches))
```

I should get 380 matches instead of 200 matches.

Comment: Right.  The HTML content is never modified.  What the Javascript does is modify the DOM -- the Domain Object Model -- which is a set of objects stored in a tree in memory.  You can use Selenium to scroll through that tree, but there is no "master HTML copy" that gets modified.

Comment: How do we scroll through the tree? Can you give an example?

Comment: To retrieve all elements: 1st iteration of script ~200 elements -> Scroll to button "show more" -> show_more.button.click() -> 2nd iteration to retrieve the rest. For an unspecified amount of elements you would need to check for the existence of the next element to not throw exceptions. And for not getting loading issues webdriver.wait() is a good option.

Comment: *How do we scroll through tree?* -- You go read the Selenium documentation.  There are thousands of sample Selenium applications on the web.  Also, you throw out BeautifulSoup.  You need to switch to Selenium's API for finding the elements.